# Show enum description instead of value when debugging

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I work with visual studio code and I'm using the following enum:

```
export enum Car {
    Toyota,
    BMW,
    Audi,...
}
```

When I debug, the debugger shows the value 0, 1 instead of the enum description like Toyota, BMW. Which settings or code modification do I need to make the debugger show me the enum description?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If don't need numeric values of enum members, you can use 'String Enum', according to the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)
it would look like:

```
export enum Car {
    Toyota = "Toyota",
    BMW = "BMW",
    Audi = "Audi"
}
```

In that case members and values would be the same, and during dubugging you will get enum descriptions like Toyota, BMW, etc.

Comment: Thank you. This is the solution i was looking for.

Comment: Please accept the answer if you find it was helpful and accurate.